# Filter not getting the data from `template.hbs` select component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to filter my data using a filter. I am sending the data to filter. But filter hasn't recives the data at all.

But my `select` component shows all data what i passing. what is the issue? how to get the sending `array` of data in to fitler?

here is my hbs file which works fine.

```
{{#rdc-form-select  label="Select Balance" 
                labelPosition="top" tabindex="0"
                options=(sort-by-amount selectedCreditCard.balances)
                selected=selectedBalance
                searchEnabled=false
                renderInPlace=true
                onchange=(action 'selectedBalaceType' ) as |data|
            }}
            {{data.balanceType}} : {{data.amount}} //show the data!!
            {{/rdc-form-select}}
```

here is my helper.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function sortByAmonut([params, value1, value2 ]) {
    console.log('select values are', params, value1, value2 );
    //params is : <(unknown mixin):ember824>, value1:undefined,value2 undefined
    return params;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(sortByAmonut);
```

**UPDATE**

I have removed the `value1` and `value2` from filter. but just on console i am getting the foloowing:
[image: console gives this]

Comment: may be typo `(sort-by-amount` it should be `(sort-by-amonut`

Comment: I have made the changes. but still not working. I am using `jsonapi` format

Comment: You are just sending only `selectedCreditCard.balances` to helper, but you are trying to destructure to three properties `params, value1, value2`. reading [helpers ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_helper-names) might help..By the way you are receiving the data in your helper you can start using it return the data in helper.

Comment: @kumkanillam - I agree. for a sample I tried for `value1` and `value2`. I have removed those. still I am not able to get the array data. but how come I am getting int he select box then?

Comment: We need more info regarding `selectedCreditCard.balances` how its prepared and what is it?. but I think you can solve this, there will data in `content`, you can try using `params.content` and return the required array of stuff to options

Comment: I am trying to consoel the `params.content`, it has 2 values as `canonicalState` and `currentState` both have 2 array. but I am not see any values inside. each one is `InternalModel`